# PHP setting cookie time to past wont delete it

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with unsetting cookies. At the moment, i am unable to log out. Cookies itself works like a charm while validating user session.
So upon first login i am setting cookies in this way (on successful login):

```
$cookie_username = $username;
$cookie_password = sha1(md5($password));
$cookie_value = 'username='.$cookie_username.'&hash='.$cookie_password;
$cookie_name = 'remember_me@website';
$cookie_time = time() + 31536000;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_time, '/', '.website.com');
```

Cookies above work well and i dont have problems with reading them.

This is my logout code:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600, '/', '.website.com');
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
unset($_SESSION['username']);    \
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);    / were setted after successful login
```

According to what i have read around SO this should work and delete cookies, however they dont :(

Comment: Are you sure the cookie_name is the same thing, and that you haven't already outputted any content to the page causing setcookie to fail?

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt yes, cookie name is a separate variable in parent file (these scripts are included) so it cannot be different. Also, this code is included at the very top of the page source code, so yea - im sure

Comment: Try a greater different, e.g. time() - 86400

Comment: don't use relative times for cookie expiry. you're depending ENTIRELY on the user's clock being relatively accurate. it's safer to set a "distant past" time, e.g. Jan 2/1970. Anyone whose clock is THAT far out deserves any problems they might experience.

Comment: i changed `time()-3600` to `time()-360000` and cookie still exist according to dev console in ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure the cookie's name, domain, path, and even security settings are all identical to what you're attempting to delete.

If you created the cookie like this:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+3600);
```

and then attempted to delete it like this:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()-3600, '/', '.website.com');
```

That won't work. You have to have the exact same parameters that were used when creating the cookie.

If you created the cookie in JavaScript, double-check your settings there.

As a test, try all of the following code. If it works, comment out each one-by-one, until you're only left with the one that worked:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600);
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600, '/');
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600, '/', '.website.com');
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600, '/', '.website.com', 1);
```

Comment: Pity, but none of the above code worked. This probably happenes since i might forgot unsetting valuable params.. Is there a way to unset the entire session and all the cookies' params?

Comment: The only mystery is the value of `$cookie_name`. Are you positive the value of this is set like you're expecting? Try removing this variable, and type in the actual cookie name as a normal string.

Comment: I found whats the problem in. Cookies do not overwrite, however i am doing them in similar way. I am able to log out only if i delete existing cookie and setting past cookie as a new one. But.. how to delete existing cookie in php?

Comment: Fixed. Solution was to remove `.website.com`. Somewhy. However i tried all of you 4 suggestions (setted and rewrite with same params)

Comment: So then my solution of: setcookie($cookie_name, '', time()-3600, '/'); was correct.